# Adding additional fields to form

Tags: html, forms, textfield

I currently have this page Rahman | Khaliq | Contacts
What I am trying to do is have a guest choose yes or no, if they choose no, and click submit. I will get The answer no with their name to my email.

If they choose Yes, then I want a dropdown box to appear with numbers 1 though 10. If they choose 1, then a input box shows up so they can put the name of the guest. If they choose 2 then 2 input boxes show up, so on and so forth.

All fields should be required if they choose yes.
The submit should send me the results to my email...

Let me know your guys thoughts.
Thank you very much.

Comment: any effort to show from your side?

Comment: Could you show us some code so we know where to begin?

Comment: Its not allowing me to paste the code, it is showing it all messed up. Can you go to the page http://rahmankhaliq.com/rsvp.html and view the source code.

Comment: 1. paste the code into the editor, 2. select all and press `ctrl + k` or `command + k`

Comment: Its not allowing me to, but you can find the code on http://rahmankhaliq.com/rsvp1.html      The issue now is that it seems like I can't enter information in to the input fields, also the submit btn dosnt show up, there should be a submit btn regardless if they choose yes or no, and once clicked submit the results should be emailed to me....